# Pixel movement C++

Tags: pixel

This may or may not be a very stupid question so I do apologise, but I haven't come across this in any books or tutorials as yet. Also I guess it can apply to any language...

Assume you create a window of size: `640x480` and an object/shape inside it of size `32x32` and you're able to move the shape around the window with keyboard inputs.

Does it matter what `Type` (int, float...) you use to control the movement of the shape. Obviously you can not draw halfway through a pixel, but if you move the shape by 0.1f (for example with a `glTranslation` function) what happens as supposed to moving it by an `int of 1`... Does it move the rendered shape by 1/10 of a pixel or?

I hope I've explained that well enough not to be laughed at.

I only ask this because it can affect the precision of collision detection and other functions of a program or potential game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

glTranslate produces a translation by x y z . The current matrix (glMatrixMode) is multiplied by this translation matrix, with the product replacing the current matrix, as if glMultMatrix were called with the following matrix for its argument:

1 0 0 x 0 1 0 y 0 0 1 z 0 0 0 1
If the matrix mode is either GL_MODELVIEW or GL_PROJECTION, all objects drawn after a call to glTranslate are translated.

Use glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix to save and restore the untranslated coordinate system.

This meaning that glTranslate will give you a translation, to use with the current matrix, resulting in non decimal numbers. You can not use half a pixel. glTranslate receives either doubles or floats, so if you are supposed to move it 1 in x,y or z, just give the function a float 1 or double 1 as an argument.

http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glTranslate.xml

Answer (score 1):

The most important reason for using floats or doubles to represent positioning is the background calculation. If u keep calculating your position with ints not only do you have to probably use conversion steps to get back to ints. You will also lose data every x amount of steps

Answer (score 0):

if you want to animate you sprite to have anything less than 1 pixel movement per update then YES you need to use floating point, otherwise you will get no movement. your drawing function would most likely round to the nearest integer so it's probably not relevant for that. however you can of course draw to sub pixel accuracy!